# How to deal with bogus and unethical journals?how to stop unethical journals?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, publishers, online-publication

In research and publications there are database maintains good quality list of journals, Maintaining a reliable good impact factor too. But on the other side there are list of journals who publish anything for money. They give misleading information about their indexing and even some unbelievable Impact factors.

We find difficulty in publishing one quality paper in a quality journal .while the other hand there are people publishing plagriazed text and repetitive papers in regular way and just dumping the research papers in databases with such unethical journals. Its annoying for me to see these kind of habits been followed.

HOw could you handle such thing. Give our suggestions?

Avoiding is always better but you cant avoid when you see a man publishing 10's of papers for year with these kind of journals and you publishing papers in single digit but its a quality research.

comment name of such unethical journal

Comment: I don't understand the question. Since nobody forces you to submit your papers to a bogus or unethical journal, there is nothing that needs to be dealt with. Can you clarify?

Comment: I am not submitting. Is there any way to stop such unethical journals?

Comment: Ok, "how to stop unethical journals" is a valid question, I recommend that you edit your question accordingly. Concerning that question, my personal recommendation would be not to focus your efforts on that. There are simply too many of them, and nobody serious cares about the publications in those journals anyways.

Comment: you are right. Better to not care about them

Comment: Sounds more like a rant than a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem you should simply don't care about. Do good research and sooner or later it will be recognized.

People taking shortcuts will always exist and you cannot do anything against. Just ignore and go straight.

Comment: You said it right. Sad part is even the people in higher positions of an institution aren't aware of this and choosing this shortcut. That's annoying for me.

Comment: I agree and it often happened to me too. However bothering with the problem would take you any further. Better to bet on doing even better research, etc. You know, Latins were used to say "Those who know how to do things, just do those things. Those who do not know how to do things, they become boss. Those who do not know how to command, become politicians"...

Comment: Very well said proverb. It has deep meaning to get. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

What can you do? Essentially, nothing. Neither the garbage journals nor the people who publish in them are, in general, doing anything illegal so nobody's really in a position to stop them. Delete the spam and get on with your life.

Bear in mind that, in any competitive situation, such as hiring and grant applications, the people on the relevant committees will value quality publications much more than publications in scam journals. So the one thing you can do is to do your job properly if you are on such a committee.